# Quickblox 2.6.1 webrtc: missing org.webrtc.videocapturerandroid$nativeobserver

Tags: android, webrtc, videochat, libjingle, quickblox-android

I am getting a missing class error when trying to load libjingle_peerconnection_so.so. I am using Quickblox 2.6.1 video webrtc. Does anyone have any idea whats going on?

##---------------Begin: proguard configuration for Gson  ----------
    # Gson uses generic type information stored in a class file when working with fields. Proguard
    # removes such information by default, so configure it to keep all of it.
    -keepattributes Signature

```
# For using GSON @Expose annotation
-keepattributes *Annotation*

# Gson specific classes
-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }
#-keep class com.google.gson.stream.** { *; }

# Application classes that will be serialized/deserialized over Gson
-keep class com.quickblox.core.account.model.** { *; }

##---------------End: proguard configuration for Gson  ----------

##---------------Begin: proguard configuration for quickblox  ----------

#quickblox core module
-keep class com.quickblox.auth.parsers.** { *; }
-keep class com.quickblox.auth.model.** { *; }
-keep class com.quickblox.core.parser.** { *; }
-keep class com.quickblox.core.model.** { *; }
-keep class com.quickblox.core.server.** { *; }
-keep class com.quickblox.core.rest.** { *; }
-keep class com.quickblox.core.error.** { *; }
-keep class com.quickblox.core.Query { *; }

#quickblox users module
-keep class com.quickblox.users.parsers.** { *; }
-keep class com.quickblox.users.model.** { *; }

#quickblox messages module
-keep class com.quickblox.messages.parsers.** { *; }
-keep class com.quickblox.messages.model.** { *; }

#quickblox content module
-keep class com.quickblox.content.parsers.** { *; }
-keep class com.quickblox.content.model.** { *; }

#quickblox chat module
-keep class com.quickblox.chat.parser.** { *; }
-keep class com.quickblox.chat.model.** { *; }
-keep class org.jivesoftware.** { *; }
-dontwarn org.jivesoftware.smackx.**

#quickblox videochat-webrtc module
-keep class org.webrtc.** { *; }

##---------------End: proguard configuration for quickblox  ----------

##---------------End: proguard configuration --------------
```

[Missing class error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGmvH.png)

Answer (score 0):

did you put `libjingle_peerconnection_so.so` for all Jni folders??

like `x86,armeabi` etc.

Comment: Yes of course i did, that's why this problem is giving me a head ache... could it be the libjingle version, and if so what site would i get the latest version? I am using the version that came with Quickblox webrtc 2.6.1

Comment: @Edison did u got solution?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the error. I updated the correct version of libjingle in the right path. thanks for your help.